# switching UIViewController while using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an app for iPhone. My problem is, I have a uiviewcontroller that has something like a shortcuts menu. From there, I want to be able to switch page to any on storyboard but just presenting it like this

```
[self.mainID dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{
                             checkin_vc *sampleView = [[checkin_vc alloc] init];
                             [self.mainID presentViewController:sampleView animated:YES completion:nil];
                         }];
```

doesn't seem to cut it. nothing happens, and if I try to present it without dismissing the current controller first, then I get a black screen, most likely because I'm trying to present an object of class, not the actual view controller that is set up on the storyboard.

i tried

```
[self.mainID dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{
                             UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                             checkin_vc *sampleVIew = (checkin_vc *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkin_sid"];
                             [self.mainID presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil];
                         }];
```

dismiss is done and I'm returned to previous view controller, but completion part never gets done.

I also get this warning:

> 2014-05-12 00:05:31.388 Roborder[5503:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: it's just 
-(id)initMe: (id)mainc segue:(NSString*)seg
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    
    self.seg = seg;
    
    self.mainID = mainc;
    return self;
}

what is passed is "self" of the view controller i want to use there.

Comment: Ok with this "self.mainID dismissViewControllerAnimated" you dismissed the view controller after that you are trying to present view controller on that with this "[self.mainID presentViewController]" so here it is not getting the self.mainId

Comment: Can you explain your requirement a bit?

Comment: change [self.mainID presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil]; with [self presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil]; i think this will solve your current issue

Comment: problem is, the class I'm calling this from is not a view controller. it was ment to be something like a controller for my shortcuts menu only. that's why i passed current view controller to it

Comment: You can try with this [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil]

Comment: -[UIWindow presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d74a20 when i try that :/

Comment: Then you have store the last view controller and do like this [self.lastviewcontroller presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Use ContainerView , then switch to  any viewController  use, [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardIdentifier"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with storyboards is that instantiating via alloc init isn't going to work. Firstly make sure that every view controller you may call has, in the storyboard, a storyboardID set. It's just a unique string but you can use it as below to instatiate:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
checkin_vc *sampleVIew = (checkin_vc *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkin_vc"];
//present as original code.
```

It's late though so let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question :)

Comment: you got the question right.

i tried it and now i get 
Warning: Attempt to present <checkin_vc: 0x16df4e70> on <profile_page_vc: 0x16dc6460> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! i got this before swell tho but i think your method is right, i probably messed up somewhere else

Comment: edit: 
i tried with this code

[self.mainID dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                 checkin_vc *sampleVIew = (checkin_vc *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkin_sid"];
                                 [self.mainID presentViewController:sampleVIew animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];

but now it just dismisses, never does the completion.

Comment: my problem was indeed elsewhere, but this part was also wrong in my original code, so I'm gonna accept it as an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Cocoadelica's code is correct, but you need give your checkin_vc an Identifier in the storyboard to present it-- check the left panel -- show the identity inspector -- put a string in "Storyboard ID" (for example: checkin view controller)-- then you can use it in the code like this

   `checkin_vc *sampleVIew = (checkin_vc *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkin view controller"];`
2. you should not dismiss the shortcut menu(if it's your root menu) cause you're checkin_vc will lost it's parent(viewcontroller).
3. here's my sample code of viewcontroller switch, hope it will help you:

in the MenuViewController.m

```
    -(IBAction)GotoShop:(id)sender {
      ShopViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShopController"];
      [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
```

this will present the shopViewController

and in the ShopViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)QuitShop:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This will dismiss the shopViewController and return to it's parentviewcontroller --- in this case back to MenuViewController

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to wrap my head around this. 
but you hinted a problem, when i release profile page vc, which is the parent of the class I'm trying to present the checkinvc from, my completion block can't be executed cuz it's released together with it, or is it? eh I'm so very new to iOS :)

Comment: my recommendation would be to slow down a little, read the Cocoa programming guide and the View Controller Programming guide and you'll get your bearings.

Comment: @Hypnotick well, I think you maybe misunderstand the vc structure. when you start an app, you always have an enter point -- which is root vc of the app, this enter point vc shall never be dismissed, if it's dismissed, the app will crash (or quit?). If your profile page vc is not the root vc , do not present the checkinvc in profile page vc, instead, present the checkinvc from profile page's parentvc.

Comment: i went through some tutorial and saw this what u posted high wing, it solved the problem :D thanks anyway!